# Context Node Add Form and Wrong Button Position

Tags: 7, forms, panels

I created a context node add form and added it to the panel page.
The form is displayed in the page but, "Save" button is wrongly positioned. 
[image]

Another form also has the button wrongly at the top instead of bottom.
I updated the button's weight from my custom code to move the button underneath of the form, but it doesn't work.
I used CCK fields in my form.
I'm looking for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the submit button separately from the contact form?

If you are using an override to the node add/edit form in panels, try this:

**1.** Click on the little gear of your region to add content

**2.** Select Node form submit buttons which is under the "Form" heading

**3.** Position the form submit buttons where you want.

We had a similar problem on a Drupal 6 installation, and I think it may work on Drupal 7 as well.

Hope this helps